# how do i rename a forked fiddle on jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

how do i rename a forked fiddle on jsfiddle.

In particular, I am forking the React Getting Started with JSX fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

```
<div id="root">

</div>
```

But when I fork and save, I just get the same titled fiddle in my dashboard.  I want to have several different React projects going so this is problematic when I want to easily distinguish between all the files since right now they all appear with the same name

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I notice that it works only if you you put the name and then fork.

For instance if you already had one with the random string, I generally open it give the name and then I click on the fork button.

Then I delete the one with the random string.

I hope this work for you

Answer (score 8):

On the left side click on "Fiddle Meta" and you can enter a new name and/or description:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marvin.  I did that, but the only way I can get that change to persist, showing up in my dashboard is to either "fork" or "set as base" after I change the name and description.  When I do nothing or click "Update" the change in name/description seems lost once I navigate away from the page.  Is there another way, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is [a rather old topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsfiddle-users/M8B5r_dGNJ0) on google groups saying that "set as base" is indeed the way to go. Seems to be by design. I don't have a dashboard to verify, though.